# Можно ли как-то уместить несколько методов списка в одну строку?

Tags: python, строки, функции, список

У меня есть функция для сортировки списка и удаления первого и последнего индекса:

```py
def listFilter():
    intList.sort()
    intList.pop()
    intList.pop(0)
```

Могу ли я каким-либо образом сократить тело функции до одной строки и таким образом вообще искоренить функцию из моего кода и оставить просто эту строку?

*я только начал учить Python, не обессудьте, пытаюсь сразу делать код как можно компактнее - приучать с детства, скажем так*

Comment: Для стандартного списка - никак. Можно написать свой класс списка, каждый метод которого будет возвращать сам же список, но это лишний гемор.

Comment: именно с этими методами - нет. а вот res = sorted(intlist)[1:-1] - похоже то, что вам нужно. но я не проверял.

Comment: В общем случае не надо делать код как можно компактнее любой ценой. Надо его делать так, как принято в языке. А дзен Python говорит: "ясность важнее лаконичности". Т.е. иногда надо оставлять несколько строк.

Comment: @Сергей
1) Ваше предложение я попробовал, однако оно не сработало, так как второй `.pop` выдает ошибку: **Cannot find reference 'pop' in 'None'** (PyCharm), в тоже время с последним `.pop` все великолепно работает.
2) Спасибо за совет, я буду его придерживаться в дальнейшем! :)

Comment: @strawdog, да, не работает с этими методами и работает, как вы предложили. А почему (что за правило) не работает с методами? Я полагал, что сначала отработает `sort`, потом один `pop`, и затем еще один. Что мешает?

Comment: потому что ваша задумка будет работать, если метод возвращает измененные исходные данные. а ваши методы так не делают, в частности pop возвращает вырезанную часть списка, а не список без вырезанной части. поэтому читайте документацию на методы.

Comment: qoopdata, я удалил свое предложение, как увидел ответ strawdog, но вы были быстрее. Чего-то я пока не знаю.

Comment: @strawdog Спасибо за объяснение, почему оно не работает! Я стал больше понимать в логике списков, немного открыло глаза)

Comment: @strawdog, да, верно, спасибо большое. Смешно, что я сам всегда советую читать документацию в таких случаях. Но был уверен почему-то, что все эти методы списков проводят изменения на месте и изменённый список возвращают. Надо было включить голову.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попроще можно так

```py
a = [3, 10, 1, 0, 456, 2]
a = sorted(a)[1:-1]    # вот ваше решение
print(a)

# OUT
# [1, 2, 3, 10]
```

выражение `[1:-1]` означает, взять срез от второго элемента (поскольку индексация начинается с 0) до последнего, не включая его.

Comment: Спасибо, достаточно просто и понятно!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать для этой цели сторонний пакет `fluentpy`. `_f` оборачивает объект в `Wrapper` который для всех методов, возвращающих `None`, возвращает сам объект. `._` разворачивает объект обратно.

```py
import fluentpy as _f

def filter_list(a_list: MutableSequence):
    return _f(a_list).sort().pop().pop(0)._
```

Comment: Пока для меня трудно, однако спасибо за предложение! Возможно применю ваше решение.

Comment: Если Вы пока что только учите Python и не стоит какой-то конкретной задачи, где это было бы весьма кстати и удобно, я не рекомендую использовать этот пакет. В нативном Python стоит выучить, когда метод возвращает сам объект, а когда `None`. Пакеты, подобные этому ([`pipe`](https://pypi.org/project/pipe/) в их числе) были созданы с целью сделать функциональное программирование на Python более элегантным, так как его родные конструкции слишком монструозны (map, lambda и прочие).